# How to add the Stamps tag in Rest API call using Apex

Tags: docusignapi, apex

What is the Stamps tag to be used in Rest API request for docusign using apex  and stamps tag anchor string to be added in pdf document to map the tag.

Comment: Can you please share your usecase, why you need to use Stamp tags in your document? Normally stamps are used for Japanese documents as eHanko stamps.

Comment: This is to get the stamps on the contracts signed by the clients in order to fullfil business requirement; Since these documents are required to get the client signature as well as the stamp.

Comment: DocuSign stamps is not switch on by default, you need to contact DocuSign support or your DocuSign Account Manager to switchon the stamp feature from backend

Answer (score 0):

As Amit K says in his comment, the stamps feature is currently not enabled by default in the Demo environment. Contact your DocuSign technical or business contact to have the feature enabled.

At this time (Nov 2017), the feature is aimed at the Japanese market.

Comment: Thanks Amit I found the solution for adding the stamp to the document by API call; Now whats happening is that i have two documents in envelope and I have stamp and signature for both the documents on the second page. But the problem is for the first document it adds the right tags but for the second document it doed not work right it adds the signature tag for both signature and stamp anchor string. Here is my API resquest for adding the signaure and stamp to the already created envelope having two documents.

Comment: "signHereTabs" : [ {
    "stampType" : "signature",
    "anchorString" : "s1"
  }, {
    "stampType" : "stamp",
    "anchorString" : "stamp_1"
  } ],
}